# How to check if a major mode derives from another?

Tags: major-mode

Is it possible to check if a mode is derived from another mode?

eg:

```
(member major-mode '(c-mode c++-mode glsl-mode))
```

Could be replace with something like this:

```
(does-mode-derive-from major-mode cc-mode)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Function `derived-mode-p` does that.

So in your case: `(derived-mode-p '(c-mode c++-mode glsl-mode))`. `C-h f` tells you:

> **`derived-mode-p`** is a compiled Lisp function in `subr.el`.
>
> `(derived-mode-p &rest MODES)`
>
> Non-`nil` if the current major mode is derived from one of `MODES`.
>
> Uses the `derived-mode-parent` property of the symbol to trace backwards.

This is its definition, in case you want to be able to pass `major-mode`:

```
(defun derived-mode-p (&rest modes)
  "Non-nil if the current major mode is derived from one of MODES.
Uses the `derived-mode-parent' property of the symbol to trace backwards."
  (apply #'provided-mode-derived-p major-mode modes))
```

(@phils pointed out in a comment that `provided-mode-derived-p` is available only starting with Emacs 26.)

Comment: Regarding the last part, note that `provided-mode-derived-p` was only added in 26.1.

Comment: @phils: Good to know. I added that to the answer. Thx.